# Restore `/usr/bin/latex` on ubuntu

Tags: latex, texlive

I wanted to uninstall texlive on ubuntu and used `apt remove texlive` but some program still found `/usr/bin/latex` so I removed that by hand (`rm`). When I reinstalled texlive with `apt install texlive` the `/usr/bin/latex` file was not restored.

Comment: `app remove texlive` is not supposed to do anything. Did you mean `apt remove texlive`?

Comment: Don't `rm` stuff in `/usr/bin` or you might break your system. Use `dpkg -S` to find the package that owns a file and remove that package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find out which installed package the file the you deleted belongs to using

```
dpkg -S /usr/bin/latex
```

Then reinstall that package (it's probably `texlive-latex-base`)

```
sudo apt install --reinstall texlive-latex-base
```

Answer (score 3):

It may be a good idea to install `texlive-full`, so that all available LaTeX packages are installed as well (you won't get `missing something.sty` errors, and wouldn't have to manually find how to fix them).

The following command should reinstall any missing files.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall texlive-full
```

Comment: I tried `sudo apt install --reinstall texlive`, `ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/latex': No such file or directory`

Comment: I want to avoid the additional ~5GB of `texlive-full`. I mean who installs *all* python packages whenever they install python? That seems like a weird practice. The ones I actually need will pile up soon enough

Comment: @FelixB. when you use Ubuntu distribution packages for Tex Live (instead of the native `tlmgr` package manager) then you cannot (easily) install individual additonal LaTeX packages. There are a number of predefined package collections that you can install but it can take a bit of trouble to find out which collection you need for a specific LaTeX package. Therefore it is easier to just install `texlive-full` and be done with it, 5GB is not so much these days with terrabytes of disk space and fast internet (and some packages are not in a separate collection, only in `texlive-full`).

Comment: @Marijn okay fair enough. I am usually using miktex and this is ubuntu inside wsl which I did not want to clutter up immediately for some cross platform testing. I guess one should use `tlmgr` instead then